# Doubly linked list: Incompatible pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, struct, doubly-linked-list

at the moment I'm working on an implementation of a balanced B-Tree in C. I decided to use doubly linked lists but I have run into some problems. At the moment I get warnings for line 94, 95 and 96 because apparently the pointer types are incompatible. 
I really don't see how and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int data2exists; // no: 0 , yes: 1
    struct node * parent;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * middle;
    struct node * right;
} node;

node * insert(int *, node *, node *);
void getInput(int *);
node * createNode(int *);
void quickSwap(node *, int *, int *, int *, int *);
node * splitLeaf(int *, int *, int *, node *, node *);
void printTree(node *);

void main() {
    int input;
    getInput(&input);
    node * root = createNode(&input);
    getInput(&input);
    insert(&input, root, root); // returns current pos
    getInput(&input);
    insert(&input, root, root); // returns current pos
    getInput(&input);
    insert(&input, root, root); // returns current pos
    printTree(root);
}

node * insert(int * input, node * root, node * currentPos) {
    printf("data1: [%i], data2: [%i], d2exists: [%i], input: [%i]\n", currentPos->data1, currentPos->data2, currentPos->data2exists, *input);
    if (currentPos->left == NULL && currentPos->middle == NULL && currentPos->right == NULL) {
        // no children
        if (*input > currentPos->data1 && currentPos->data2exists == 0) {
            // data1 < input, no data2

            currentPos->data2 = *input;
            currentPos->data2exists = 1;
            return(currentPos);
            // printf("CASE1: data1 < input, no data2, no children\n");
        }
        if (*input < currentPos->data1 && currentPos->data2exists == 0) {
            // data1 > input, no data2

            currentPos->data2 = currentPos->data1;
            currentPos->data1 = *input;
            currentPos->data2exists = 1;
            return(currentPos);
            // printf("CASE2: data1 > input, no data2, no children\n");
        }
        if (currentPos->data2exists == 1) {
            // data2 exists
            int smallest;
            int middle;
            int largest;
            quickSwap(currentPos, input, &smallest, &middle, &largest);
            printf("s: [%i] m: [%i] l: [%i]\n", smallest, middle, largest);
            root = splitLeaf(&smallest, &middle, &largest, currentPos, root);
        }
    }
    return(currentPos);
}

void printTree(node * root) {
    if (root->parent != NULL) {
        printf("printTree() did not receive root!!!!\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("%i || %i", root->data1, root->data2);
        printf("\n");
        // printf("%i || %i", root->left->data1, root->left->data2);
        // printf("\t\t");
        // printf("%i || %i", root->middle->data1, root->middle->data2);
        // printf("\t\t");
        // printf("%i || %i", root->right->data1, root->right->data2);
        // printf("\n");
    }
}

node * splitLeaf(int * smallest, int * middle, int * largest, node * currentPos, node * root) {
// this function needs to return root!
    if (currentPos->parent == NULL) {
        // currentPos is root
        // create a parent with median
        node * root = createNode(middle);
        node * left = createNode(smallest);
        node * middle = createNode(largest);
        // genau hier gehts weiter! hier müssen root, left und, middle verknüpft werden!
        root->left = left;
        root->middle = middle;
        left->parent = middle->parent = root;
        // printf("root-addr: %i, left->parent: %i\n", root, left->parent);
        return(root);
    }
}

void quickSwap(node * currentPos, int * input, int * smallest, int * middle, int * largest) {
    // writes values to *smallest, *middle and *largest ordered by size

    if (currentPos->data1 > currentPos->data2) {
        *smallest = currentPos->data2;
        *middle = currentPos->data1;
    }
    else {
        *smallest = currentPos->data1;
        *middle = currentPos->data2;
    }
    if (*input < *smallest) {
        *largest = *middle;
        *middle = *smallest;
        *smallest = *input;
    }
    else if (*input < *middle) {
        *largest = *middle;
        *middle = *input;
    }
    else {
        *largest = *input;
    }
}

node * createNode(int * input) {
    node * ptr = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->data1 = * input;
    ptr->data2 = 0;
    ptr->data2exists = 0;
    ptr->parent = NULL;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->middle = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;
    return(ptr);
}

void getInput(int * input) {
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf(" %i",input);
}
```

Comment: @quinxorin It gives the warnings when you compile with `-Wall -pedantic` (which you should always have enabled).

Comment: No, even without -Wall or -pedantic. Something went a little wrong with my installation so when I use -Wall i get about a 100 warnings that are just caused by the gcc..

Comment: Ah, you're right, I was assuming that was the case. Can you not reinstall GCC, `-Wall` and `-pedantic` are very useful (and should just be enabled inside GCC by default).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha! The problem is a tricky one. It has to do with the definition of your `node` struct. The members `parent`, `left`, `middle` and `right` are of type `struct node` but you `typedef`ed the struct to be `node` directly. My guess is that GCC ignores the undefined `struct node` and hopes it's defined somewhere else.

In other words: the type `node` exists, but `struct node` doesn't. Therefore when you try to assign a `node` to a `struct node` GCC doesn't know what to do. So change

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} node;
```

to

```
typedef struct node {
    ...
} node;
```

Although it might be wiser to use another name for the `struct node` than the type `node`.

Some nitpicks:

- GCC complains that `main` doesn't return an `int` (just `return 0;`)
- In `splitLeaf` you're redeclaring the arguments `int * middle` to `node * middle` and the same with `root`.
- `splitLeaf` doesn't return anything when `currentPos->parent` isn't `NULL` (though maybe you haven't finished the function yet)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going crazy over this. Wouldn't have thought of this in a million years..

Comment: "*...Although it might be wiser to use another name for the struct node than the type node ...*" Yes, yes, yes! +1 :-)

Comment: You're very welcome. This has become another reason for me to not `typedef` my `struct`s.